# Imacros issue scraping text on webpage after a <br>

Tags: imacros

in my macro I have selected the text to copy

TAG POS=1 TYPE=p ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT

below is the html code on the website.

```
<p><span class="blue">Address:</span>  8306 West Maple br
Wichita, KS 67209 </p>
```

The macro only scrapes "Address: 8306 West Maple" and ignores the text after the 
 tag. How can I include this text so that I scrape "Address: 8306 West Maple Wichita, KS 67209".

Also would like to separate the text into individual columns in a csv file. I have 100+ pages so this data obviously will be different on each page but the format is the same.

col1, 8306 West Maple
col2, Wichita
col3, KS
col4, 67209

here is my full macro code

```
VERSION BUILD=11.5.498.2403
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !PLAYBACKDELAY 0.2
SET !DATASOURCE "plumbingUrls.csv"
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
URL GOTO={{!COL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=p ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=2 TYPE=P ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=3 TYPE=P ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=4 TYPE=P ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\Users\LMFServices\Documents\iMacros\DataSources\ FILE=Extract_plumbingUrls.csv
WAIT SECONDS=2
```

Comment: It is not clear exactly what is your question.

Comment: When I run my macro... the csv file generated scrapes "Address:  8306 West Maple" instead of "Address: 8306 West Maple  Wichita, KS 67209". It that even though I am scraping the text in the <p> tag it is not copying the text after the <br> in side the <p> tag.